# How to find SUM of all rows which have unique value

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I'm making financial script and in the end of every month I need the final sum of all invoices. If the invoice has 4 or 10 rows every row contains the full sum.

So I need to find distinct invoice numbers and than sum their value.

```
SELECT finalprice 
FROM invoices 
GROUP BY invoicenumber;
```

finalprice

```
   87.26
  153.72
   10.56
  979.20
  136.20
   47.10
  112.62
```

This gives me every unique row but doesn't sum them, when I try with:

```
SELECT sum(finalprice) 
FROM invoices 
GROUP BY invoicenumber;
```

**sum(finalprice)**

```
  349.04
 1690.92
   10.56
11750.4
  544.8
  141.3
 1351.44
```

This SUMs every row in the unique `invoicenumber`, but I need to sum every unique invoice value.

Comment: We need original sample data and desire output. Right now you only show us your current result. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: thanks this is my 1st question

Comment: No problem. Leave a message when you update your question so I get a notification. Just add `@JuanCarlosOropeza`

Answer (score 2):

Just create a derivate table where you remove duplicates

I belive you only want a single total value so dont need a group by.

```
SELECT SUM(finalprice) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT invoicenumber, finalprice
      FROM invoices) t;
```

Also you can use your version

```
SELECT SUM(finalprice) 
FROM (SELECT finalprice 
      FROM invoices 
      GROUP BY invoicenumber) t;
```

**NOTE**: derivated tables need alias so I just use `t`.

Comment: No, it just shows all values of every distinct invoice, but don's SUM's them. I need only one result, all SUM.

Comment: No, doesn't work, both gave same result SUM(finalprice)  
61161.51, but the real number must be 34450.38.. :(

Comment: Well as I say In my comment provide source data and desire output. Otherwise your requirment isnt clear

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to just divide by the `count()`:

```
SELECT sum(finalprice)/count(*)
FROM invoices 
GROUP BY invoicenumber
```